# how to sort a particular value at the beginning?

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i display the word Not Listed at the very beginning so that even in my dropdown menu it shows at top then rest of the datas?

```
items
-------

id    name

1     some name 1
2     some name 2
3     some name 3
4     Not Listed
5     some name 4
6     some name 5
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional sorting:

```
select * from items
order by name <> 'Not Listed', name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KyxZz27bBhdnATMfVUzDt/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name        |
| --- | ----------- |
| 4   | Not Listed  |
| 1   | some name 1 |
| 2   | some name 2 |
| 3   | some name 3 |
| 5   | some name 4 |
| 6   | some name 5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I phrase this using `DESC` so the `ORDER BY` expression can be what wants to be first:

```
order by (name = 'Not Listed') desc, name
```

It is a quirk of MySQL that "false" sorts before "true".  Hence, put the "true" expression and use `DESC` to make it first and `ASC` to put it last.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by FIELD(name,'Not Listed') desc` as follows

```
select * from table_name
order by FIELD(name,'Not Listed') desc
```